# using IQueryable to filter gridview using ids

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, iqueryable

Hi and thanks in advance,

I have several functions that alter my gridview. So to know whats in the current view, I wanted keep track of the ids. Current code below:

```
public void getCurrent_GridView()
{

    if (GridViewFacility.DataKeys.Count > 0)
    {
        WISSModel.WISSEntities context = new WISSModel.WISSEntities();

        //Prepare to build a "Base" query:
        IQueryable<WISSModel.Base> searchListQuery = context.Bases;

        for (int i = 0; i < GridViewFacility.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            String id = GridViewFacility.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString();

            //Refine query, one search term at a time
            searchListQuery =
            searchListQuery.Where(p => p.isDeleted == false && (p.BaseId.ToString().Contains(id)));


            //txtSearch.Text += id + " ";
        }

        txtSearch.Text = "test" + searchListQuery.ToList().Count;

        GridViewFacility.DataSource = searchListQuery.ToList();
        GridViewFacility.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridViewFacility_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{

    getCurrent_GridView();
    GridViewFacility.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    LoadData();

}
```

In VS2013, I get this error:

> **An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code**
>
> *Additional information*: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the message is rather clear, you can't use `.ToString()`

In linq to entities, you can use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`... to convert some numeric values to string. It's only available for decimal and double, but you can cast an int to a double.

I guess your error is on the line

```
p.BaseId.ToString().Contains(id)
```

If `BaseId` is an int, you can replace this by

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.BaseId).Contains(id)
```

Comment: Althaus Thanks I'm not getting that error anymore, but my query count comes up with 0 outside the loop which is not putting any data in datasource.

Comment: @Neo84 Well, I would guess your "cumulative" where are doing something like AND clauses, when you need OR ? Not easy to answer with just that code...

Comment: ahhh yes OR did help, but if counts whatever rows in the db, not the current state of the gridview. Any thoughts why this happens . This is why I wanted to use IQueryable.